# categorize non-functional requirements

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I am developing a machine learning project which analyzes requirement specification and categories the non-functional requirements in to categories like database, web socket, backend technology, etc. As I have researched Naive Bayes is the better way to categorize but due to lack of dataset I have planned to go with Seed LDA for topic modeling. Would it be okay to use LDA or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try either LDA or clustering.

Based on my experiences, k-mean clustering could help you have a better visualization about what are you doing and what is happening.

With LDA, it could also be good. You can try it first since k-means take much more time.

I implemented an issue tracking system here using k-means, may you like to take a look. [issue tracker](https://github.com/yeulam1thienthan/TrendAnalysis-and-IssueTracking-in-NLP)